# Multi-tenant SPA in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I try to build a multi-tenant SPA using Aurelia where the tenant is given as:

- http://myapp.example.org/tenant1
- http://myapp.example.org/tenant2
- http://myapp.example.org/tenant3

How can I return the same index.html for all of these urls (while being able to extract the tenant in the SPA code for Oauth2 login)?

I have made similar AngularJs solutions but then I used a "trick" by implementing a Asp.net web api that accepted a {tenant} route. Is there a simple "all Javascript" Aurelia way of doing this?

Comment: Couldn't you simply create a route, like `route: "/:tenant"`

Comment: Are you familiar with .htaccess files and/or URL rewritting?

Comment: A route would come after the hash so that would be something quite different, I think. Not really what I'm looking for.
As for the URL rewriting: I'm not sure how I would use that in this context

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "redirect" all those pages to index without changing the URL is by doing it in the server, with a URL rewrite. The thing you did in ASP.NET MVC was exactly that.

If you want to do that only with javascript, you'll need to redirect all those pages to index and pass the tenant as a parameter. For example:

```
location.href = location.host + "/?tenant=" + location.search;
```

The problem here is: by doing that, you'll really need all those tenant pages phisically, what I suppose it's not what you want.

There is another try: you can also make a default 404 page and then make that redirect from there, but you'll throw an 404 error to the client, what I don't think it's good at all.

So, if you're using IIS or any other server, you should just do a rewrite and everything is gonna be ok.

If you're using NodeJS or .NET you can see how to do it directly from the Aurelia's documentation.
http://aurelia.io/docs.html#configuring-push-state